# Solana artwork upload command problem ( metaplex )

Tags: solana, metaplex, candy-machine

{
"price": 1.0,
"number": 10,
"gatekeeper": null,
"solTreasuryAccount": "",
"splTokenAccount": null,
"splToken": null,
"goLiveDate": "25 Dec 2021 00:00:00 GMT",
"endSettings": null,
"whitelistMintSettings": null,
"hiddenSettings": null,
"storage": "arweave-sol",
"ipfsInfuraProjectId": null,
"ipfsInfuraSecret": null,
"nftStorageKey": null,
"awsS3Bucket": null,
"noRetainAuthority": false,
"noMutable": false
}

Comment: In which directory do I need to save config.json file in metaplex. so I can run this command: npz ts-node ~/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-v2-cli.ts upload \
    -e devnet \
    -k ~/.config/solana/devnet.json \
    -cp config.json \
    -c example \
    ./assets

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can have the config file anywhere on ur PC. In simples terms and following the command that you shows, you need to have the config file in the same folder where you have the assets folder.

Other way to see it, is that you need to have config.json in the same folder that your terminal/cmd is. For example if you open a terminal and is at */home/your_user*, then you need to have config.json at the home folder on your user.

Other way to do it, is just adding the full path of ur config.json to the *-cp* flag, for example: `npz ts-node ~/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-v2-cli.ts upload -e devnet -k ~/.config/solana/devnet.json -cp ~/my/full/path/to/config.json -c example ./assets`, where the pc will find the config.json at `/home/your_user/my/full/path/to/config.json`

Hope this can solve your doubt, if you have any other question drop a comment on this answer.